# C++: Overloading << operator with function pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class "stampstream" that is essentially intended to work like 'cout'. The two functions that follow are outside the class. This is the part that works.

```
class stampstream: public std::ostream
{
    //code
    stampstream& operator<<(stampstream& (*x)(void))
    {
        //code
    }
    //code
};

stampstream& endr()
{
    //nocode
}

stampstream& (*endrow)(void)=endr;
```

In main:

```
stampstream s;
s << "teststring1" << endrow;
```

Note that "endrow" is essentially 'endl'. This part works perfectly fine, compiles and executes with the right output.
Now, I'm trying to overload << with another possible row(int) function. This is the part that doesn't work. Again, it's part of the same class as above and the following 2 functions are outside the class.

```
class stampstream: public std::ostream
{
    //code
    stampstream& operator<<(stampstream& (*r)(int y))
    {
        //code
    }
    //code
};

stampstream& ro(int y)
{
    //nocode
}

stampstream& (*row)(int)=ro;
```

In main:

```
s << "teststring2" << row(5);
```

This is the error I get:

```
error: invalid user-defined conversion from ‘stampstream’ to ‘stampstream& (*)(int)’ [-fpermissive]
```

What am I doing wrong with row ?

Comment: Hint:  What is the type of `row(5)`?

Comment: row is of type stampstream with int parameter

Comment: And *when you call it*, as you do when you say `row(5)`, what does it return?  A `stampstream`, not a pointer to a function.

Comment: It doesn't return anything, but neither does endrow and that works perfectly fine. Yeah, it's supposed to be a stampstream type return.

Comment: @Prasad: Actually, `s << endrow();` doesn't work.  See what's wrong yet?

Comment: You're not *calling* `endrow`.  That's why it works.

Comment: I have no operations to perform in the endrow (endr) function itself. Hence the //nocode.
Operations are performed inside the class under the overloading.
The reason endrow is there is because without it the compiler tells me endrow was not declared in this scope

Comment: `s << endrow` works, `s << endrow()` fails, `s << row(5)` fails.  Do you see any pattern?  Have you tried `s << row` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt, yeah I do. I'm just not clear on where the format conversion is happening and faulty.

Comment: Do you know what the `()` means?

Comment: It's a parameter list for a function...

Comment: It's the "function call operator".  It appears to the right of a function or pointer-to-function, **calls it immediately**, and evaluates to the result (return) of the function call.  If you want `s << row(5)` to work, then `row(5)` needs to return something that `operator<<` can accept.

Comment: There's a certain computation that needs to happen inside the class where the row function is accepted by overloading <<. If the row function (outside the class) is of type stampstream, what should I be returning, since I can't return *this ?

Comment: @Prasad: You're starting to stumble upon the reason function objects exist.  :P

Comment: @cHao I'm unsure how to proceed at this point. This is the last obstacle I'm facing in this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
s << "teststring2" << row(5);
```

function call has higher precedence than `<<`, so this calls the function `row` points at and then tries to pass its return value (a `stampstream &`) to `operator<<`.

What you want is

```
s << "teststring2" << row;
```

This doesn't call the function and instead passes the pointer to `operator<<`.  Inside *that* function, when you want to call `x`, you'll need to provide the argument.

It sounds like what you are *trying* to do is to have a function `row` that creates a functor object that you can then pass to `operator<<`.  You can do that in C++11 with a lambda:

```
class stampstream: public std::ostream
{
    //code
    stampstream& operator<<(std::function<stampstream&(void)> r)
    {
        //code
    }
    //code
};

std::function<stampstream&(void)> row(int x)
{
    return [x]()->stampstream & {
        //code
    }
}
```

Which you can call as:

```
s << "teststring2" << row(5);
```

The call to `row` happens first, which constructs a lambda and returns it (but doesn't yet run the code in it).  The functor is passed to `operator<<` and when that function calls `r`, it will call the code in the lambda (which can refer to the `x` param, which was bound by value, so copied into the lambda.)

Comment: I got a bunch of errors, but mainly this brings me back to: error: ‘row’ was not declared in this scope... since I'd assume it doesn't have the stampstream type.

Comment: 'a bunch of errors' probably indicates your compiler doesn't support C++11

Comment: I'm using the g++ compiler. I tried g++ -std=c++11... This is what I'm getting: error: declaration of ‘operator<<’ as non-function
   stampstream& operator<<(std::function<stampstream&(void)> r).

error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration.

error: expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token.

error: ‘function’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
 std::function<stampstream&(void)> row(int x).

stampstream.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
error: ‘row’ was not declared in this scope
   s << "teststring2" << row(5).

Comment: @Prasad You also need to `#include <functional>`.

Comment: Thank you! It compiles.. Now I'm wondering what I'm supposed to have after return [x]()->stampstream & {... what I'm trying to do requires a private class member data. Also how do I use the parameter 5 passed into row 5 inside the class under the overloaded << ? Wouldn't the parameter need to be passed all the way to the operator overloader?

Comment: @Prasad Because you want to access data members from the `row` function, this is not how it should be done. Instead follow the code in my answer but make this change: Change all `std::ostream&`  to `stampstream&`. Now in the `<<` function your will be able to access data members through the `os` parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I managed to use this solution by keeping a global variable that helps me exchange the number I need to pass from function to class.

Answer (score 2):

Since Chris has already answered your question, I wanted to advise you of alternatives to your current method:

1. Your `stampstream` class should use a specialized `std::streambuf` that writes out the stamp inside `overflow()`. There's no need to extend an `std::ostream` and reimplement the input operators. For an example of how to do this, [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118713/add-time-stamp-with-stdcout).
2. You seem to be using `endrow` and `row` like manipulators. Operator overloads already exist for manipulators that do not take arguments at the call site. You can have `endrow` take and return an object of type `std::ostream&`. For `row` you can have it return a class that overloads the inserter to allow the syntax you want:

   ```c++
   struct row_impl
   {
       row_impl(int row) : row(row) { }
       // Write out the row and return the stream
       friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, row_impl const& rimpl);
   private:
       int row;
   };

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, row_impl const& rimpl)
   {
       // This is where the code for your original row() function goes
   }

   // write out to and return the stampstream instance
   std::ostream& endrow(std::ostream& os);

   row_impl row(int row)
   {
       return row_impl(row);
   }
   ```

   Now `s << endrow` and `s << row(5)` will work without having to add anything to your `stampstream` class.

Comment: That was the original solution proposed.. I wanted to try it alternately. But thank you :)